# Trying to run a virtual machine with Gnome Boxes on Fedora 37 always starts with QEMU boot error

Tags: fedora, virtual-machine, qemu, libvirt, gnome-boxes

I tried to run Gnome OS, Fedora Silverblue and endeavourOS with Gnome Boxes (Flathub install) on Fedora 37. However, regardless of system, booting into the virtual machine immediately stops with:

[image]

The steps I took were pretty default:

1. Install Gnome Boxes via Flathub
2. Open Gnome Boxes and choose 'Create Virtual Machine'
3. Install GnomeOS Nightly (2nd time Fedora Silverblue) from pre-configured source
4. Start Virtual Machine

If I check my virtualization capabilities, everything looks fine:

```bash
$ gnome-boxes --checks
• The CPU is capable of virtualization: yes
• The KVM module is loaded: yes
• Libvirt KVM guest available: yes
• Boxes storage pool available: yes
• The SELinux context is default: yes
```

The image are at the right place and accessible to libvirt:

```
$ virsh list ; virsh vol-list gnome-boxes
 Id   Name           Status
------------------------------
 1    gnomenightly   laufend

 Name           Pfad
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 gnomenightly   /home/firestarter/.local/share/gnome-boxes/images/gnomenightly
```

The QEMU logs show some warnings of `qemu-system-x86_64: warning:` This family of AMD CPU doesn't support hyperthreading(2) `(I have a AMD Ryzen 5 5500U)`. However, this should not be a problem here as far as my research have told me.

UPDATE: So it appears, that it relates to the default uefi boot modus of Gnome OS and Fedora Silverblue. Trying another image, Manjaro, which offers me the option to boot in BIOS the virtual machine boots. Using UEFI option for the same image, the boot fails as before; although `edk2-ovmf` is installed.

Comment: Does your image have a UEFI partition? Or do you need to change the VM settings to use a BIOS?

Comment: How exactly are you creating the virtual machines? Can you update your question to include the exact steps you're going through to reproduce this behavior?

Comment: @hardillb I added the the layout of the host, though the layout of the image I canẗ tell since it is just vanilla Gnome OS Nightly as offered by Boxes pre-configured Downloads.

Comment: @larsks I added the steps, though they are really straight forward and vanilla.

Comment: It's not your physical harddrive, the message is about the virtual harddrive associated with the virtual machine

Comment: @hardillb yes, I understood that now after some more research. I also added the output of `gnome-boxes --checks` to testify my hardware capabilites. But it tells everything is fine.